# Order Room results by Date as String

Tags: android, sql, database, sql-order-by, android-room

I'm working on an app where `Dates` are entered in the Room database as `Strings`, with a `SimpleDateFormat` fixed to `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'` (e.g. "26/12/2018 10:33:31").

Without changing the structure of the database, I'd like to query some results, ordered by date. This should probably look like this (inside a `Dao`):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY stringToDate(startTime) DESC LIMIT :count")
List<Results> getLast(int count);
```

Unfortunately, this throws a compile error: "no such function: stringToDate", no matter if the function exists, even if it is annotate as TypeConverter in due form.

Moreover, since String is accepted as a Room type, I'm not event sure I could use TypeConverter here to begin with.

Is there any way I could order by `Date` as `String` without modifying the database structure ?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%d-%m-%Y', startTime) DESC LIMIT :count")
```

Make sure that the format passed to strftime match your time format.

For reference formats can be found here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm

Comment: `strftime` is meant to do the opposite of what I want: it turns an ISO date into a formated string. Surprisingly though, this half-works, as it orders as a date (which is not the case in [base sqlite](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5c7184b1b0c0a3yzjshrntwd)), but it won't take the `DESC` into account

Comment: Take a look at this link @DanChaltiel
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-time-2b4cf9672b98

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing `stringToDate(startTime)` to `datetime(startTime)`?

Can you provide a sample of startTime object?

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer - if you want to request more information about the question - ask for it im a comment

Comment: I am sorry, I know that but I do not have enough points to post a comment